# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed when using Chef's Knife ssh

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, chef-solo, chef

Facts:

1. I have a Chef server installed.
2. I have registered a node to this server, and I can see the node in the webUI (This is an existing node, NOT bootstrapped using knife bootstrap
3. When I execute the command

   ```
   $ knife ssh "role:test" "sudo chef-client"
   WARNING: Failed to connect to node[ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal] -- Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: ubuntu@ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal
   ```

Is there something I have missed? e.g. copy the SSH keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by not having the right private key PEM file added to your local ssh agent.  Doing something like:

```
$ ssh-add pk-XXXX
```

Where the argument is the private part of the key pair used to create the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your error message that it's trying to log in as the "ubuntu" user. Make sure this user is getting the correct key put in it's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. I'm not sure about Ubuntu instances but I know the Amazon Linux systems only have the key copied to the ec2-user account. You would have to script or manually copy the key for that user.